# CartoDB: Import Error: host and port must be set

Tags: carto, installation, centos

I have setup cartodb in one of the server (CentOS). Everything worked fine in development environment, but when I move to production environment I couldn't import any file. Getting the below error in production.log

```
Ignoring statsd, because there were a error loading the config
[table#create error] === #<RuntimeError: host and port must be set>
```

Below the importer job log,

```
2014-06-17T10:44:54Z || Before dispatch
2014-06-17T10:44:54Z || new_importer()
2014-06-17T10:44:54Z || Fetching datasource public_url metadata for item id http://cartodb.s3.amazonaws.com/static/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip
2014-06-17T10:44:55Z || File will be downloaded from http://cartodb.s3.amazonaws.com/static/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip
2014-06-17T10:44:55Z || Before run.
2014-06-17T10:44:57Z || Starting import for /tmp/imports/20140617-14039-17m47zj/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip
2014-06-17T10:44:57Z || Unpacking /tmp/imports/20140617-14039-17m47zj/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip
2014-06-17T10:44:57Z || Importing data from /tmp/imports/20140617-14039-166nffe/tm_world_borders_simpl-0.3.shp
2014-06-17T10:44:58Z || Detected encoding WIN1252
2014-06-17T10:44:58Z || Using database connection with {:adapter=>"postgres", :encoding=>"unicode", :host=>"localhost", :port=>5432, :database=>"cartodb_user_d13717ee-414f-4c29-a4e9-19e1d48c197b_db", :username=>"postgres", :user=>"cartodb_user_d13717ee-414f-4c29-a4e9-19e1d48c197b"}
2014-06-17T10:44:59Z || ogr2ogr call:      OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO PG_USE_COPY=YES PGCLIENTENCODING=WIN1252 SHAPE_ENCODING=WIN1252 /usr/local/bin/ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user=cartodb_user_d13717ee-414f-4c29-a4e9-19e1d48c197b dbname=cartodb_user_d13717ee-414f-4c29-a4e9-19e1d48c197b_db password=71fc094fbf3ac1d38de9cc90ac3eeed821df33f0cartodb_user_d13717ee-414f-4c29-a4e9-19e1d48c197b active_schema=cdb_importer" -t_srs EPSG:4326  -lco DIM=2 -lco PRECISION=NO /tmp/imports/20140617-14039-166nffe/tm_world_borders_simpl-0.3.shp  -nln cdb_importer.importer_6cd598c4f60c11e383fd00185162f697 -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI
2014-06-17T10:44:59Z || ogr2ogr output:
2014-06-17T10:44:59Z || ogr2ogr exit code: 0
2014-06-17T10:44:59Z || Georeferencing...
2014-06-17T10:44:59Z || Disabling autovacuum for "cdb_importer"."importer_6cd598c4f60c11e383fd00185162f697"
2014-06-17T10:44:59Z || Creating the_geom from wkb_geometry column
2014-06-17T10:44:59Z || replace empty strings by nulls?
2014-06-17T10:44:59Z || no string column found, nothing replaced
2014-06-17T10:44:59Z || geometrifying
2014-06-17T10:44:59Z || casting wkb_geometry to geometry
2014-06-17T10:44:59Z || Converting to 2D point
2014-06-17T10:44:59Z || Total processed: 246
2014-06-17T10:44:59Z || Total processed: 246
2014-06-17T10:45:00Z || FINISHED: Converting to 2D point
2014-06-17T10:45:00Z || geometrified
2014-06-17T10:45:00Z || Renaming column wkb_geometry TO the_geom
2014-06-17T10:45:00Z || Enabling autovacuum for "cdb_importer"."importer_6cd598c4f60c11e383fd00185162f697"
2014-06-17T10:45:00Z || Georeferenced
2014-06-17T10:45:00Z || Finished importing data from /tmp/imports/20140617-14039-166nffe/tm_world_borders_simpl-0.3.shp
2014-06-17T10:45:00Z || Proceeding to register
2014-06-17T10:45:00Z || Before renaming
2014-06-17T10:45:00Z || Before moving schema
2014-06-17T10:45:00Z || Before persisting metadata
2014-06-17T10:45:01Z || Dropping table tm_world_borders_simpl_0_3
2014-06-17T10:45:01Z || Import Error: host and port must be set
2014-06-17T10:45:01Z || After run.
2014-06-17T10:45:01Z || After dispatch
2014-06-17T10:45:01Z || SUCCESS!
```

Which host/port are missing and where to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following varnish management setting next to

`production: 
          <<: *defaults`

solves the import issue.

```
varnish_management:
    critical: false
    host: '127.0.0.1'
    port: 6082
    purge_command: 'purge'
    url_purge_command: 'url.purge'
    retries: 5
    timeout: 5
```

Comment: Did this work for you? I'm getting the same message but to me it looks like CartoDB is looking for the port and host of a graphite server, not the varnish server.

I tried the instructions above, but it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: It worked for me. May be some other configuration also needs to be modified for you. Could you share your config file of SQL-API and Windshaft?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, but it wasn't the varnish server for me. The same error message is given (in version 2.13.3 at least) if the graphite and graphite_public config options aren't set in app_config.yml.

```
graphite_public:
    host: "example.com/graphite"
    port: "80"
graphite:
    host: "127.0.0.1"
    port: "2003"
```

I'm not even sure that a graphite server needs to be running. Just adding these to the config file seemed to make my problems disappear.